# Scheduling jobs in salesforce using customization

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

How to schedule jobs in salesforce which run on daily basis using customization .
Her i should also be able to know the number of days remaining

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Do you want to know how to schedule jobs via Apex code?  What are you trying to customize?

Comment: i want to know whether it is possible to schedule jobs via built in customization.If not how do we do using apex code.Give me some example

Comment: I think you meant 'config' or 'configuration' instead of 'customization'

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can schedule Apex classes for execution using configuration only. Below is the screenshot of the screen that shows all the option you get. In order to get to this screen go to Setup > Develop > Apex Classes and click Schedule Apex button in the top of the list view.

[image]